# Position div without it going off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of items. They each have a pop up with a description. The problem is that the last item on the list, when clicked, the pop-up is half off of the screen.

```
$('ul').on('click', '.link', function () {
    $(this).next('.div').toggle();
});
```

The list is dynamically generated so I can not assign an individual class to each item and then set a position for each pop up. Is there a pragmatic approach to I could take to this?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in fiddle. I did not get any error when click last item. But I have a small suggestion that changing toggle() to sliderToggle() maybe better.

```
$('ul').on('click', '.link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.bubble').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking. I've updated the fiddle showing a clearer example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4jzq6m8s/3/

I think you need something like that:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $bubble = $(this).next('.bubble');
    $bubble.toggle();

    var right_offset = $bubble.offset().left + $bubble.outerWidth(true);
    var window_width = $('body').outerWidth(true);
    if (right_offset > window_width) {
        var margin_left = window_width - right_offset;
        $bubble.css('margin-left', margin_left);
    }
});
```

Check out jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use this css to get the bubble popout from right for every 4th item of the list:

ul li:nth-child(4n) .bubble{right:5px; left:auto;}
ul li:nth-child(4n) .bubble:after {right:13px; left:auto;}

Hope it helps. Thanks